# Does APNS add the device token to feedback server if the device is unreachable for a long time?

Tags: iphone

If I go abroad for a vacation for a month and my iPhone has no data/Wifi connection or if I have turned off my phone for a long period of time, in both case APNS will not be able to deliver push notification to my iPhone. My question is, will APNS think the device token is "bad", therefore adding it the the feedback server?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't.

1. You send notifications to APNS
2. APNS sends notifications to each device
3. The device tells APNS if it rejects the notification (uninstalled app, ...)

From :

If a provider attempts to deliver a push notification to an application, but the application no longer exists on the device, **the device reports that fact to Apple Push Notification Service**. This situation often happens when the user has uninstalled the application. If **a device reports failed-delivery** attempts for an application, APNs needs some way to inform the provider so that it can refrain from sending notifications to that device. Doing this reduces unnecessary message overhead and improves overall system performance.